# FTP SITE CHMOD Error

Tags: security, centos, ftp, chown

When trying to edit file/folder permissions via FTP I am getting the error:

**505 Security server forbids SITE commands. Contact admin.**

I am currently using VSFTPD with the config value chmod_enable=YES set.

I also tried using ProFTPD instead but I got the same error.

I have two servers that are setup in a similar environment and they both report the same error.

I am struggling to find anything for that error through google and with it being ftpd server independant I am thinking it must be a system setting or maybe something intercepting the FTP command before it even hits my server if possible?

Would appreciate any help as I am having to do CHMOD commands through shell at the moment which isn't great as I would rather not require everybody to login to SSH.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If two independent FTP daemons report the same error, the filesystem permissions for the FTP useraccount are insufficient to perform the chmod.

wat does `ls -l /location/of/ftp/folder` report ?

Comment: `code
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 Feb 23 11:25 cache

drwxr-xr-x 4 user group 4096 Feb 23 11:26 libs

drwxrwxr-x 2 user group 4096 Feb 23 14:20 templates_c

`

I can confirm the correct user permissions are set, and I can run the chmod command at command line level.

I think an immediate work around is to implement SFTP rather than FTP at our end

Answer (score 0):

What I find most interesting about this issue is that neither the `proftpd` nor `vsftpd` source code bases have the string "Contact admin".  This, to me, suggests that the error message your FTP client is receiving is **not**, in fact, coming from the FTP server.

A search on Google for that error string turned up a few different posts, all of which point toward the issue being a [Checkpoint firewall](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=10022.0.2917673.2504701), sitting between your FTP client and FTP server, being the culprit.